# Databinding and Eventhandles - Passing Parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a Windows WPF application that bind an Observablecollection of Objects of type 'Person' to a listbox. The Person is displayed via a template, and this template generates an 'Expander' for each person (i.e, "see more details about Mr.X"). On expasion I want to do something in the background (so I add an eventhandler 'Expander_Expanded', but also I need the program to remember which expanders were expanded, i.e., I'd like to pass the 'name' of the person into the event. Although I found some similar questions I did not quite understand the answers...

Also, maybe someone knowledgeable of the language architecture can explain why the language not allow the following, most logical solution: Add a property to the person class

```
public ExpanderName {get{return "Expander_"+this.Name;}}
```

and then bind the name of the expander to this,

```
<Expander Name="{Binding ExpanderName}" Expanded="Expander_PersonDetails">
```

then one could access the name of the person that was expanded in the eventhandler by recovering it from 'sender.name'. The compiler hwever says that the 'name' of an UIcontrol element cannot be bound. Why?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Name is not a bindable property, it needs to be known at compile time so that the compiler can generate the proper object to be accessed in code-behind.

What you can use is the generic Tag property - you can bind anything you want to it, and then you can access it in code. Try this:

```
<Expander Tag="{Binding ExpanderName}" Expanded="Expander_PersonDetails">

void Expander_PersonDetail(object sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
{
  var expander = (Expander)sender;
  string expanderName = (string)expander.Tag;
}
```

A better solution would be to bind (two-way) the Expander.IsExpanded property to a field directly in the Person class - this way you will always have the correct state stored in the correct object, and the handling will be much simpler.

Comment: Didn't know about the 'Tag'... Nice! This works really well! I didn'T want to do it via twoway binding because in other parts of the application I want to save these settings for the next startup, write tem to XML etc. Thanks a lot!